# Record syntax for a constructor

Tags: haskell

I wonder why does this work

```
data Person = PersonContructor {
  firstName :: String,
  lastName :: String,
  age :: Int
} deriving (Show)

main = putStrLn $ show $ map (PersonContructor "firstName1" "lastName1") [666, 999]
```

and this doesn't

```
data Person = PersonContructor {
  firstName :: String,
  lastName :: String,
  age :: Int
} deriving (Show)

main = putStrLn $ show $ map (PersonContructor {firstName="firstName1", lastName="lastName1"}) [666, 999]
```

and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While Constructors act like curried functions in general, so you can partially apply them as in your first example, the record syntax constructing wants to construct a complete record with no fields left out.

If you want to name the fields nevertheless, you can use a lambda:

```
map (\age -> PersonContructor {firstName="firstName1", lastName="lastName1", age=age}) [666, 999]
```

Comment: Or for a little added convenience, use `-XRecordWildCards` and then `\age -> PersonConstructor {firstName="firstName1", lastName="lastName1", ..}`.  The `..` fills in the rest of the fields with variables of the same name that are in scope.

Comment: For completeness, there's also [`NamedFieldPuns`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#record-puns) and `\age -> PersonContructor {firstName="firstName1", lastName="lastName1", age}`; since `age` is written without an equals sign, with this flag on, it becomes shorthand for `age=age`.